# How to disable all elements (also the ones not currently visible in the screen) in a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with a set of elements. When I click one of the I would like to disable all the others. If I click again on the selected item all the other items are enabled again.

I tried the different proposed solution without success. I hope someone can help me.

This is my code:

```
//action to take when a presentation is selected
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
          int position, long id) {
        //disable the other items when one is selected
         if(position!=selectedPresentation){
              for(int i=0;i<parent.getCount();i++){
                  if(i!=position)//disable all the items except the select one
                        parent.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
              }
              selectedPresentation=position;

          }else if(selectedPresentation==position){
              //enable again all the items
              for(int i=0;i<parent.getCount();i++){
                  parent.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(true);
              }
              selectedPresentation=-1;

          }
```

Where selectedPresentation is a global variable storing the selected item. If no item is selected its value is -1.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to keep one flag isEnable in your list data and try to change flag value whichever is click and also change rest of list item value after this try to notify list and set enable-disable in getView() base on flag state.

Comment: Like a giant radio group.

Comment: The problem is that getView() is called at the beginning to create the list when u scroll(to make new element appear) or add a new element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your own subclass of ArrayAdapter that has [AreAllItemsEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled%28%29)() return false, and define [isEnabled(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled) to return false for a given item in your the ones you want to disable.

In your custom ArrayAdapter overide isEnabled method as following

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

## other option

Don't implement `onItemclickListener`. This will not give you any update of item `click`. Only register onClick listener to `views`.

Answer (score 0):

You may take another object of the List(Arraylist) which is populating elements in listview then on click copy the corresponding position data to new arraylist you made and then notifyDataSet and when you click again you populate listview with original list so it will apear again....Just do this trick it might work for you

Answer (score 0):

parent.getChildeAt() only work for visible Item.
you should change something in adapter.
if make custom adapter then you can do some thing like  @ṁᾶƔƏň ツ answer, but if you use default adapter you can change adapter's arraylist that before you pass it to adapter.
put boolean in it (in arraylist) and in on item click true/false it for all item.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this solution and seems it works fine!

```
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                  @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
              int position, long id) {
            //disable the other items when one is selected
                        Toast.makeText(context, "onClick called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // this will flash up twice

                      if(position!=selectedPresentation){
                         selectedPresentation=position;
                  for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                      if(i!=position)//disable all the items except the select one
                            adapter.isEnabled(i);
                  }


              }else if(selectedPresentation==position){
                  //enable again all the items
                  selectedPresentation=-1;
                  for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                      adapter.isEnabled(i);
                  }


              }
```

And in my adapter I wrote:

```
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
   if(selectedPresentation==-1 || selectedPresentation==position)
       return true;
   return false;
```

Now my concern is how to show the items in the listView as disabled